# How does edit count work?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

According to the statistics displayed on my suggested edits. I mean

[image: Edit Statistic 1]

According to what is shown above. I have **120 edit suggestions approved** but in my badge progress

[image: Edit Statistic 2]

Its shows **82 edits**.

I even just got my [`Strunk and White`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) Badge. My Question is how are edits counted and what is the reason for the inconsistency?

Comment: See the **Editor, Strunk & White, Copy Editor** section under [**Moderation Badges**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732) for detailed information on how the editing badges are calculated.

Comment: @animuson Why is my post closed as duplicate. My question is how edits are counted not about badges???!!!

Comment: Because that indicator you're looking at is a **badge progress indicator**. That is not the *total number* of edits you've made, but the number of edits you've made that count towards the badge. You can see your raw total of revisions in your [activity history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2509901/precioustijesunimi?tab=activity&sort=revisions).

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi You're asking about the difference between the numbers, note all the "do not count"s in the badge description for copy editor

Comment: @animuson I get it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The badge keeps track of *posts* that you've edited.  The review stats are the total number of edits that you have suggested.  The difference is the number of posts that you've edited multiple times.

Comment: Oh. ok i get it now. THANKS!!!